# How to put the output of `dput` in one line in R?

Tags: r, dput

How to make the output of `dput` be displayed in one line in R?

How to copy to the clipboard the string obtained with `dput`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take `dat <- head(iris)` for example:

1. Make one-line output for `dput()` displayed in the console:

```r
cat(capture.output(dput(dat)), "\n", sep = "")
```

Output:

```
structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4),     Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9), Petal.Length = c(1.4,     1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7), Petal.Width = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2,     0.2, 0.2, 0.4), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,     1L), levels = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

2. Copy to the clipboard (Windows only):

```r
writeClipboard(paste(capture.output(dput(dat)), collapse = ""))
```

Comment: I like both the question and both answers. But I would like to know in which scenario this could be relevant? Many thanks!

Comment: When providing the data on a Stack Overflow question, it takes less vertical space to put everything in one line

Comment: Note that it only works when `dat` is not too big

Answer (score 4):

To copy paste directly the output of `dput`, you can use `write.so` with `write_clip = T` from the `read.so` package:

```
#devtools::install_github("alistaire47/read.so")
library(read.so)
write.so(head(iris), write_clip = TRUE)
```

output

```r
iris <- data.frame(
  Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4),
  Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9),
  Petal.Length = c(1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7),
  Petal.Width = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4),
  Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"), class = "factor")
)
```

Comment: Hi Maël! It seems like your answer only answers the second part of OP's question (the clipboard part), but doesn't answer the first bit (the dput displayed in one line part)

Answer (score -1):

Take *`dat <- head(iris)`* for example:

`dat <- head(iris)`

Install the packages--> "*datapasta*"

#`install.packages(c("datapasta"), dependencies = TRUE)`

Use *dpasta* (note: only works if you're using **RStudio**)

`datapasta::dpasta(dat)`

output-->

```r
named list()
> data.frame(
+   Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4),
+    Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9),
+   Petal.Length = c(1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7),
+    Petal.Width = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4),
+        Species = as.factor(c("setosa","setosa",
+                              "setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa"))
+ )
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Copy to the clipboard ( using Rstudio )-->

`datapasta::dmdclip(dat)`

Comment: It does not put everything in one line

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).